# as3 erasing text on a graphics object

Tags: actionscript-3, text

I have a project i'm working on that allows the user to "Type" text onto a graphics object (in this case it is a canvas). So the text follows the mouse cursor and whenever a user types text appears on the graphics object. If the user clicks, the text is pasted down onto the graphics object. I need to figure out how to allow the user to make this text go away (for when the graphics object gets too crowded). What method could I use to erase all the text inside the graphics object?

Screenshot (hopefully this helps, I know this is a difficult to understand question):

> [image]

The white background is the graphics object and the text is "pasted down". Now my objective is to create a button to clear all the text on the graphics object. Instinctively I would use graphicsObject.graphics.clear() but this is obviously not the solution here.

Comment: What is rendering the text? Is it just in some sort of TextField overtop of the graphics object? Something else?

Comment: Keep text on its own layer with a transparent background.

Comment: @JasonSturges Well I thought it worked great, but now I see it messed up the coordinates of where the text is typed. Usually whenever the user typed the text appeared below the cursor, now its completely across the text layer? Do you know why this would happen?

Comment: Ah nevermind, I forgot to add the text layer as a child xP thanks again Jason.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: as long as you don not store each element which should be drawn separately, you can not just delete the text. By this I mean that you need a stack with all the elements to draw and each time one of the elements changes, is added or removed,  you clear the whole canvas and repaint every element from the stack.